# click 2 times show text javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a little clicking game with javascript at the moment and I am currently stuck with a little challenge. I need it so that whenever i have clicked a button 10 times. my second value should increase by one. Maybe a little bit hard to understand, I'll try to explain it in code.

```
// Let's just say I have this variable.
var timesThatTheButtonHasBeenClickedTenTimes = 0;
// So let's say I have an amount of times clicked. 
Amount = 0;

// Whenever I click the button..The Amount increases like this.
Amount++;

// so after one click the amount should be..
Amount = 1;
// I need it so that when the button has been clicked 10 times I want to display //that. Something like this.

timesThatTheButtonHasBeenClickedTenTimes = 1;
```

Should I do this with a while loop or what.

Comment: simple. when your button is clicked, you fire a method. In this method, increment the Amount. When amount reaches to 10, increment the second value and reset Amount to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Let's just say I have this variable.
var timesThatTheButtonHasBeenClickedTenTimes = 0;
// So let's say I have an amount of times clicked. 
var amount = 0;

var counter = function () {
    amount++;

    if (amount === 10) {
        amount = 0;
        timesThatTheButtonHasBeenClickedTenTimes++;
    }

    document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = amount;
    document.getElementById('hits').innerHTML = timesThatTheButtonHasBeenClickedTenTimes;
};

document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", counter);
```

```html
<button id='mybutton'>
Click me!
</button>
<p>
  Clicks = <span id='clicks'>0</span>
</p>

<p>
  10 times hits = <span id='hits'>0</span>
</p>
```

**Hope it helps!**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var timesButtonClicked = 0;
var secondValue = 0;

if (timesButtonClicked === 10) {
    secondValue++;
    timesButtonClicked = 0;
} else {
    timesButtonClicked++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach I'd suggest is:

```js
function increment() {

  // find the current number of times the <button> has been clicked,
  // if the <button> has a data-current attribute we retrieve that
  // attribute-value and parse it as a number in decimal format;
  // if it does not have that custom data-* attribute we set the
  // variable to 0:
  let currentValue = this.dataset.current ? parseInt(this.dataset.current, 10) : 0;

  // here we update the data-current attribute to the incremented value
  // of the currentValue:
  this.dataset.current = ++currentValue;

  // we retrieve the element with the id of 'clicks', and set
  // its textContent to the value held by the currentValue:
  document.getElementById('clicks').textContent = currentValue;

  // here we retrieve the element with an id of 'numberOfTens',
  // and set its textContent to the floored value of the currentValue
  // divided by 10:
  document.getElementById('numberOfTens').textContent = Math.floor(currentValue / 10);
}

// here we retrieve the element with the id of 'clicker':
document.getElementById('clicker')
  // and bind the increment() function (note the deliberate lack of
  // parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
  .addEventListener('click', increment);
```

```css
div:empty::before {
  content: '0';
}

#clicks::after {
  content: ' clicks.';
}

#numberOfTens::after {
  content: ' tens of clicks.';
}
```

```html
<button id="clicker">Click</button>
<div id="clicks"></div>
<div id="numberOfTens"></div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:empty` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo).
  - [Pseudo-elements, `::before`, `::after`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/).
  - [`content` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#content-property).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
  - [Pre-increment variable `++variableName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()).

Comment: Thanks David! I'll ty to implement that into my code and understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the very simple solution for you problem:

```js
var clicks = 0;
Clicker = function() {
        clicks++;
        console.log('You clicked '+clicks+' times already.');
        if(clicks == 10){
          alert('Something what you want to alert.')
          clicks = 0;
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="Clicker()">
  Click me 10x times pls
</button>
```